# fadeOut DIV if not clicked

Tags: jquery

I have the following script:

```
setTimeout( "jQuery('#quick-signup, .triangle-up').fadeOut();",3000 );
```

Is there anyway that I can set it to only do this if the div (or any of it's children) haven't been clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class to the objects that were clicked:

```
$('#quick-signup, .triangle-up').on('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass("clicked");
})
```

then in your code you can use:

```
setTimeout( "jQuery('#quick-signup, .triangle-up').not('.clicked').fadeOut();",3000 );
```

Comment: A simple and efficient solution.